# find and pass index of selected radio button to an action in asp.net mvc and Razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there any body can help me to find the index of accordion menu in asp.net mvc project with Razor view.
I fill my Index page with local data (a model not from database) then clicking on a submenu and finally pass the index of accordion menu record and submenus(radio button selected index) to the action result(wanna get and pass this index to select other elements by index)

```
@model IEnumerable<Menu.Models.Room>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
int i = 1;
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div id="proboxmain" class="proboxmain">
<div class="proboxtitle" onclick="runprobox(@i)">
@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.RoomName) |
@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.ReservationNumber) |
@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.FullName)
</div>
<div id="@i" class="proboxcontent">
<fieldset style="height: inherit;">
<div id="div_Q1">
<div id="tb_Q">
<div id="Q1_text" class="shiny-html-output">
</div>
</div>
<div id="tb_Qt">
<div id="Q1" class="shiny-html-output">
</div>
</div>
<div id="div_ans">
<div id="select" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input- 
container-inline">
<div class="shiny-options-group">
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount1 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount1)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount2 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount2)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount3 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount3)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount4 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount4)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount5 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount5)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="select" value=@item.Amount6 />
Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Amount6)
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="height: 30px;">
<input type="submit" value="pay" class="jj"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
i++;
}
}
```